# Block all traffic to Beanstalk Environment Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to block all traffic to the beanstalk domain while still having a CNAME pointing towards it and only allowing that traffic to access beanstalks ressources?.

My initial idea was to have a Load Balancer with [this Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuAMg.jpg) which accepts all traffic but only routes Traffice on ports 80 and 443 to my EC2 which is managed by Beanstalk. Now the security group of the EC2 only allows traffic from the Load Balancer security group. After configuring a CNAME everything works as expected.

The only thing that bothers me is that the beanstalk environment is still accessible through the random default domain name visible in the management console when checking the beanstalk health. How do I make this domain useless while still being able to access my beanstalk environment?

I have already tried swapping the webserver to apache and uploading an .htaccess file within the deployment package.

Comment: You can redirect it to your proper domain usling alb. Did you try that?

Comment: In the application load balancer Im using the field "Host Header" for my ELB Domain but I didn't have any success.

Comment: " I didn't have any success." - sadly is not very useful without exact details of your redirect rules, listeners, and exact explanation of what errors do you get.

Comment: There is no error code. No success is referring to: Im still able to access the Beanstalk Environment through it's default domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcin is right about redirecting with the ALB.  I just blocked traffic to the Elastic Beanstalk domain name while still allowing access through my custom domain name 3 days ago, and that was how I did it.

1. Go to the load balancer tab in the EC2 dashboard
2. Select your load balancer and open the "Listeners" tab.
3. Select "view/edit rules" on the https listener.
4. Add a rule, if the host header matches your elastic beanstalk domain, redirect to your custom host.  It would look something like the image below.
5. Repeat for the http listener if you aren't redirecting http to https.

It might take a few minutes for these changes to take effect, but anyone trying to access the elastic beanstalk domain should be redirected to your domain.

[image]

Comment: Got it to work. 
Key Takeaway: Go to the ressource itself and don't configure it via beanstalk.

Comment: yep, EB is great but it hides some of the config options, probably to keep things simple.  I've found this is true with a lot of the resources EB uses.  Glad it's working.